# Server, webserver, php, mysql benchmarking

Tags: php, mysql, performance, server, benchmarking

I've been working on a enterprise application with a user base of 1000. There are about 20-30 users at any  given time using the tool and at peak times around a 100 users.

Current configuration:
**LAMP Stack**
MySQL 5.5.29, PHP 5.3.20 - CodeIgniter Framework, Front-end Action script with Flex Framework
Intel Xeon 32 Cores @ 2.9 GHz
161 GB of RAM
2 TB Hard drive 
Linux Fedora 16 OS

I have just recently received a requirement that we will be granting access to different departments which will add about 5000 more users.

I've been mostly a front-end developer with the last two years doing back-end development as well. However, I do not have enough experiencing in load balancing, what hardware configuration can support what etc.

Currently, I am building the application from the ground up trying to optimize areas with bottlenecks and also add certain features so we don't experience issues with the new additions.

First, are there any phpmyadmin type dashboards that can be installed on linux that will give me a nice GUI showing CPU load, memory usage, harddrive read/writes  etc. ?

Second, are there any suggestions from people with experience in this area on what I can do to optimize the server?

Third, is my server configuration enough to support that many users? Application will be using 75% select statements with joins to display reports and 25% of the time writing/updating to the database.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: All depends on how "hungry" your app is. That HW may be good for 300 concurrent users or only for 10... For nice text performance dashboard use the tool `dstat`.

Comment: Entire books have been written about the topic you are asking about.  I'm surprised that your question hasn't already been flagged.  In regards to metrics I've used munin a number of times and it's been a valuable tool that's not too difficult to setup and is pretty simple to understand. You can add your own custom graphs easily enough, and there are lots of existing modules you can either add or crib from.  http://munin-monitoring.org

Comment: There's this nice linux terminal and `top` command that shows you the load, `hdparm` can measure the potential of your hard drive but it's super difficult to get a nice dashboard with accurate measurements. Depending on how the app is written, what the database config is, what the hdd I/O potential is and various other parameters determine what your server will be able to do. But 32 cores and 161 GB of ram should be absolutely sufficient for a *properly written* app to fly on such a server. If it isn't, the "programmer" who developed such a system should be banned from programming.

Comment: Turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time = 1`; wait a day; use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog; then improve the two worst queries.  (We can help with that if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`.